# Why pyspark runs out of memory for a map only program?

Tags: pyspark

I have a simple pyspark programs that reads 2 text files at a time, convert each line into json object and write it to parquet file like this:

```
for f in chunk(files, 2):                
    file_rdd = sc.textFile(f)
    df = (file_rdd
          .map(decode_to_json).filter(None)
          .toDF(schema)
          .coalesce(5)
          .write
          .partitionBy("created_year", "created_month")
          .mode("append")
          .parquet(file_output))
```

I run the job with yarn and the configuration is like this:

```
conf = (SparkConf()
        .setAppName(app_name)
        .set("spark.executor.memory", '6g')
        .set('spark.executor.instances', '6')
        .set('spark.executor.cores', '2')
        .set("parquet.enable.summary-metadata", "false")
        .set("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", 'snappy')
       )
```

This looks like a map only program so why it runs into out of memory for large input file?

Answer (score 0):

Spark has a lot of moving parts. It reads the data from text to partitions (which are generally in memory), you are decoding the json which might cause issues if your line is very long (i.e. a large json object), you do a partitionBy which might have too many elements.

I would start by trying to increase the number of partitions to begin with (i.e. use repartition as opposed to coalesce which only reduces the number of partitions), I would also try to write without the partitionBy and if that fails attempt to find the longest json and try to analyze it only (i.e. map json string to length and take the longest).